Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS - Gnome: Prevent multi instance for certain app on favourites dock
On the left favourites dock app i have two app.
One it's the icon of ecosystem "Retropie":
This icon open a "minimized window" of gnome-terminal and start Emulationstation.....
The seconds it's simply "Kodi".
The favourites dock Gnome (at now 42.9) it's need one click for lauch the app. if a double click is done by mistake the app it's open in twice difference instance.
With "Retropie" it's cause twice Emulationstation twice Retroarch and etc etc
With "Kodi" a twice instance cause a lot of trouble/general instability during usage.
It's my question it's here:
Have Ubuntu a possibility to avoid this ? For certain app it's possibly to prevent this multi instance (for example VLC have an option on preferecens) ?
